# Android: About scroll views

Tags: android, scroll

The title may not be too obvious. But here is my question. I want to simulate a scroll effect similar to the scroll menu that shows up when we long click an icon on the home screen. That menu (remove, edit, change catalog etc.,) can be scrolled. Is there a layout or can someone please direct me to a tutorial?

Please let me know if my question is not clear

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: you mean like a gallery?  You can have each image in the gallery take up the whole screen.  Also there is a viewpager.  Check out the following links if so
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: Not exactly a gallery. I have buttons instead of images. And also gallery sets one item in focus at a time. But I want several items to be in view at a time. If the number of items larger than the screen width, then I need a way to scroll the items to left.

Comment: you can have a gallery(fill_parent width and height) in a relative view with buttons overlaying each image, that is how the function looks on my phone exactly.  Maybe post some pictures to clear up what you want.

Comment: have a look at the below screenshot, http://imageshack.us/f/52/shot000009e.png/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

it contains an open source code example in github as well:
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

Comment: oh... I should have mentioned it. I need this type of functionality in a widget.  Can you let me know if the code you mentioned be used in a widget as well?

Comment: do you want the widget itself to be scrollable or do you want the popup to pop when clicking something on the widget? the latter is possible since the popup is simply a view, you can have your RemoveView create and display it on click event